# Adding .targets file to .NET framework nuget won't import properly in .Net Core project

Tags: c#, .net-core, nuget, target

I have a project that creates a nuget (RawDataConverter.nuget). The framework type is .NET Framework 4.5.2.

I have a project that I import RawDataConverter.nuget into (GeoApp). The framework type for GeoApp is .NET Core 2.1. I've never had an issue importing RawDataConverter.nuget into GeoApp.

I recently added a .targets file to RawDataConverter.nuget, and suddenly GeoApp throws errors related to the nuget. I get several `"The type or namespace name 'X' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?"` errors, as if the nuget didn't import at all.

This is the .targets file:

```
<Project xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
  <ItemGroup>
    <NativeLibs Include="$(MSBuildThisFileDirectory)\..\runtimes\win10-x64\native\*.dll" />
    <None Include="@(NativeLibs)">
      <Link>%(FileName)%(Extension)</Link>
      <CopyToOutputDirectory>PreserveNewest</CopyToOutputDirectory>
    </None>
  </ItemGroup>
</Project>
```

Has anyone seen this behavior before? I'm guessing the nuget isn't importing properly in GeoApp due to this .targets file, but I'm not sure why.

Answer (score 0):

Figured it out. Had to add this line to the nuspec file:

```
<file src="..\Release64\Miw.Mshdf.Net.dll" target="lib\netcoreapp2.1"/>
```

Info regarding different libs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/reference/target-frameworks